# "Cannot find a compatible graphics card" Error when launching Dirt 5

Tags: steam, technical-issues, graphics-card, dirt-5

I am trying to play "Dirt 5" through steam but I get an error which reads:

*"Cannot find a compatible graphics card"*

[image]

I am using an AMD Radeon R9 200 Series graphics card.

[image]

I am able to play the latest Call of Duty and tens of other games. I have never ever had any problem with my graphics card on any other game. I just wanted to ask if anyone could help me solve this issue without me needing to upgrade my graphics card.

Comment: Have you updated your drivers recently(ish)?

Comment: Yes I tried this today. When I tried to update my graphics card via 'Device Manager' it tells me that the graphics card is already up to date.

Comment: Can you force the game to use your GPU through its utility (Adrenalin?)?

Comment: I tried to launch the game through the Adrenalin app just now, but I still got the same error. I'm just surprised that games like Flight Simulator work but Dirt 5 is giving me errors.